# Activator.start method never called

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have implemented some code in the start method in Activator class in purpose to open a wizard right after eclipse will be opened. I'm trying to debug it but the start method is never being called.
Any idea what can solve it?
Here is Activator code:

```java
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {

    /**
     * The constructor
     */
    public Activator() {
    }

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);

        // Call function to open a wizard
        openWizard();
    }

    private void openWizard() {

        NewProjectWizard wiz;
        final WizardDialog wd;
        wiz = new NewProjectWizard();
        wd = new WizardDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), wiz);
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                wd.open();
            }
        });
    }        
}
```

Comment: Have you set this to be the activator class in your MANIFEST.MF file?

Comment: I don't see that there. I've added the Activator as a new class. How should I link it to the manifest?

Comment: Your MANIFEST.MF should have a line like `Bundle-Activator: path.to.your.Activator`. You can also set on the first page of the form editor for plugin.xml and MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: I have this line, but the start method is still not reached.
Anything else?

Comment: No, that was the only idea I had. But just for reference, maybe you should add your MANIFEST.MF and the full path of your Activator to the question. Also, are you sure the method is not executed, or is it just the wizard that's not shown? Have you added some print statement to the start method? Does the Error Log in the Eclipse instance you start show anything?

Comment: Yes. I tried. I also created now a new plugin project and also there the start method (was created using the plugin wizard) is not reached.

Answer (score 5):

You need to configure the Activator on the Overview tab of the plugin.xml editor.

There is also the `Activate this plug-in when one of it classes is loaded` option, if you specify this then the activator will not be run unless other code references it. If you don't specify this option then your activator will only be started if the run configuration says it should be started. If it is started it may start before the UI code is fully initialized.

All the above means is that the activator is the wrong place to put UI code.

Comment: Where can I change the run configuration to call the start in the Activator?

Comment: If you are testing in Eclipse look at `Run > Run Configurations` choose your configuration, select the Plug-ins tab. Change Launch with the `plug-ins selected below only`. Find your plugin and change the auto start setting.

Comment: Also in plugin.xml "Overview" tab, you need to specify the activator class. In your case: com.***.***.***.Activator. Thanks @greg-449 for the answer. You saved my day! :)